# Keyboard "eavesdropping" just got way easier, thanks to electromagnetic emanations

Tags: keyloggers, defense

Just found this article which basically suggests that electromagnetic emanations can be used to eavesdrop on what you're typing.

http://www.engadget.com/2008/10/20/keyboard-eavesdropping-just-got-way-easier-thanks-to-electrom/

My question is, is it possible to secure yourself from such attacks?

Comment: I feel like if you're being targeted by emag vulnerabilities you're doing something wrong in life.  Blackhat 2009 presentation (http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/BARISANI/BHUSA09-Barisani-Keystrokes-SLIDES.pdf)  At this level security awareness you're putting wire meshes in your walls.

Comment: @raz, or something very, very right!

Comment: @ChrisMurray Touche :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are electronic countermeasures you could use to foil this kind of attack, like tempest hardening, or sending out jamming signals on the frequencies that your keyboard may emanate. You could also use a soft keyboard on your screen, although screens are also vulnerable to that same kind of attack.

In reality this isn't something to worry about. It is a very sophisticated attack so would have a very limited number of attackers who could carry it out. Anyone sophisticated enough to be able to carry out this attack would have many other more reliable and easier ways to get the same data, like breaking into your place and installing a physical key logger, or using a zero day vulnerability to crack your system and install stealth malware.